# undefined label error in vs 2010

Tags: c

I am using Vs 2010 and my application is in C . I have used goto in one function to jump to the return statement present in another function. The function where i used goto is defined below the one where label is present . Does the order of label defining and goto matter in C.
I am getting error " label undefined"

regards

Comment: Labels are local to functions. You can't jump to a label on a different function.

Comment: Shame on you for even trying this. That is the reason people are so hateful of goto, because people misuse it.

Answer (score 3):

The  goto must be local to the function the label is defined in. If you want to have a non-local jump you should check out setjmp/longjmp.

Answer (score 3):

As [the webpage for this Visual Studio compiler error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khfhbs6a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says, "The label used by a goto statement does not exist in the function."  You're not allowed to goto a different function because of the problems that would cause for local variable definitions.